# Dismiss modal if anywhere but UITableViewCell is touched

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a modal with a UITableView in it. I want to dismiss the modal if anywhere on the screen is touched except for the UITableViewCells inside the table view. However, you can't create an outlet for a UITableView cell to reference it in code. Currently I have this code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: UITouch? = touches.first

    if touch?.view != WHAT TO PUT HERE? {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to reference the UITableViewCells. How should I do this?

Comment: Normally I would put a gesture recognizer on the view behind the table view. The cells will capture any touches that happen within them, and in the gesture recognizer you can dismiss the modal somehow.

Comment: I added a gesture recognizer to the tableview's superview, but the cells aren't capturing the touches. Is there a specific view to which I should add the gesture recognizer?

Comment: add a big button behind UITableView. and dismiss modal on button click

Comment: My tableview takes up the whole screen even though the cells don't, so elements behind the tableview are never touched.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works. I had to resize the tableView to fit the size of its content using this method:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //Resize the tableView height to the height of its content.
    tableView.frame.size.height = soundTableView.contentSize.height

    //Set the origin of tableView to the bottom of the screen minus a 30px margin
    //(this was my tableView's original position before resizing)
    tableView.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - soundTableView.frame.size.height - 30
}
```

Then I have this method which dismisses the modal if anywhere but the tableView is touched:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: UITouch? = touches.first

    if touch?.view != tableView {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```